# Sequence of dates for non-gregorian calendar in R

Tags: r, date

I would like to get a sequence of dates for a year with 12 months- 30 days each (so no Gregorian calendar),
and I am wondering if there is some workaround in `seq.Date` or `seq.IDate` (data.table).
Thank you!

Comment: What about `seq(as.Date("2022/1/1") , by = "day" , length.out = 365)` ?

Comment: This would produce moths with 30 and 31 days. they all need tobe 30 days long..

Comment: But for February  theres no day to be 30 !!!! unless it will be characters .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- We can try this

```
as.Date(paste0( "2022/",rep(1:12 , each = 30) ,"/", rep(1:30 , times = 12)))
```

Comment: what if I wanted the sequence between given dates.. say 2020-12-20 to 2021-1-10?

Comment: this is 2 years as you wish `as.Date(paste0(rep(c(2020,2021) , each = 360), "/",rep(1:12 , each = 30) ,"/", rep(1:30 , times = 12)))[350:370]` and the indices 350 and 370 are the numbers of the days you want to take from.

Comment: This answer still does not produce a `Date` for 29 and 30 February because POSIXt doesn't support those dates, `as.Date()` will produce `NA`s for these "days".

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ISOdate()` to create date-times from numeric representations.

```r
as.Date(ISOdate(2022, rep(1:12, each = 30), 1:30))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, this gives NA for February 29-30 :(

Answer (score 0):

You are probably working with some data set that conforms to the [CF Metadata Conventions](http://cfconventions.org/Data/cf-conventions/cf-conventions-1.7/cf-conventions.html) (such as most climate projection data and lots of other environmental data sets). Of the 9 supported calendars `360_day` represents years as 12 months of 30 days. That is obviously not POSIXt compliant so you can't reliably use the builtin date functions, nor a package like `lubridate`. There is now, however, a [package `CFtime`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=CFtime) which supports all 9 CF calendars transparently.

You can create a time series for the year 2022 like so:

```
ts <- CFtime("days since 2022-01-01", "360_day", 0:359)
```

or for the period 2020-12-20 to 2021-1-10:

```
ts <- CFtime("days since 2020-12-20", "360_day", 0:20)
```

And as character strings:

```
CFtimestamp(ts)
```

The package can also create factors that are calendar-aware for further processing.